# When adding a row in HTML table, the ID is NULL

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server

I have an HTML table with 7 columns that has an insert button. Whenever the insert button is pressed, a dialog box appears and you can enter information. Upon adding the row, I want it to automatically assign the MR_ID column to whatever the MAX MR_ID is, +1. So for example if the max MR_ID is 300 and I add a row, I want that MR_ID of the added row to be 301. The MR_ID however, does not have an Identity feature on the column. I do have another column in the table, "ID", that is set as an Identity column, though it is not used in this code as of now. Currently, whenever I insert a row, the MR_ID shows as 0 in the table and is NULL in the database. MR_ID is a lookup for other tables so I can not have it set as NULL or the same number as another row. How can I do this?

I thought about writing a query that selects the MAX, adds 1, and echo the result, and assign that to MR_ID like this -> `SELECT MAX(MR_ID) + 1 FROM Table_Name` but it is not working for me.

Ajax insert script:

```
  function insertIntoTable() {

    var tableName = document.getElementById("tableNameInput").value;

    var dict = { tableName: tableName, mrName: 'Temp Object' };

    request = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "insert-copy.php",
      data: dict
    });

    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
      if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
        console.log("row inserted");
      } else {
        console.log("row failed to insert");
      }
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {

    });

  }



<?php

  $MR_ID = $_POST['MR_ID'];
  $MR_Name = $_POST['MR_Name'];
  $Buyer_ID = $_POST['Buyer_ID'];
  $MR_POC_N = $_POST['MR_POC_N'];
  $MR_POC_E = $_POST['MR_POC_E'];
  $MR_POC_P = $_POST['MR_POC_P'];

  $host="xxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxxxxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO Stage_Rebate_Master (MR_ID, MR_Name, Buyer_ID, MR_POC_N, MR_POC_E, MR_POC_P) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $result = $stmt->execute(array($MR_ID, $MR_Name, $Buyer_ID, $MR_POC_N, $MR_POC_E, $MR_POC_P));
  echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( function() {   

    var dialog, form,

      emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
      phoneRegex = /^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$/,
      mr_name = $( "#mr_name" ),
      buyer_id = $( "#buyer_id" ),
      poc_n = $( "#poc_n" ),
      poc_e = $( "#poc_e" ),
      poc_p = $( "#poc_p" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( mr_name ).add( buyer_id ).add( poc_n ).add( poc_e ).add( poc_p ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );
  console.log(allFields);

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

function addVendor() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
// ----- Validation for each input in add row dialog box -----
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( mr_name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Please enter a valid vendor name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( buyer_id, /^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/, "Please enter a valid Buyer ID" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_n, /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/, "Please enter a valid name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_e, emailRegex, "Please enter a valid email" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_p, phoneRegex, "Please enter a valid phone number" );
      console.log(allFields);
      if ( valid ) {
        var $tr = $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).eq(0).clone();
        var dict = {};
        var errors = "";
        $.each(allFields, function(){
          $tr.find('.' + $(this).attr('id')).html( $(this).val()+"-"+buyer_id );
          var type = $(this).attr('id');
          var value = $(this).val();
          console.log(type + " : " + value);
          // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
          switch (type) {
             case "mr_id":
                dict["MR_ID"] = value;
              break;
            case "mr_name":
                dict["MR_Name"] = value;
              break;
            case "buyer_id":
                dict["Buyer_ID"] = value;
              break;
            case "poc_n":
                dict["MR_POC_N"] = value;
              break;
            case "poc_e":
                dict["MR_POC_E"] = value;
                break;
            case "poc_p":
                dict["MR_POC_P"] = value;
                break;
            }
        });
        console.log(dict);
        $tr.find('.mr_id').html( $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).length + 1 );
        $( "#html_master tbody" ).append($tr);
        dialog.dialog( "close" );


        var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "insert-copy.php",
          data: dict
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("row inserted");
          } else {
            console.log("row failed to insert");
            console.log(response);
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });


      }
      return valid;
    }
```

HTML/PHP for Table:

```
<?php
    /* Foreach loop that brings in information to populate table */
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>">
        <td class="mr_id" id="<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" id="mr_name-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" name="field" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" id="buy_id<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" id="poc_n-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" id="poc_e-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" id="poc_p-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Where is `buyer_id` defined in this line `$tr.find('.' + $(this).attr('id')).html( $(this).val()+"-"+buyer_id );` in your code?

Comment: it is defined in the javascript function that is just above the code i posted....i edited my post and pasted in the entire function so you can see.

Comment: Why cant you make MR_ID an identity column? thats what they are for.  What happens if two sessions select the MAX()+1 concurrently?

Comment: As an aside, your code is at risk of SQL injection, read this: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php and for method, this is why it's wrong: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#90209

Comment: @AlexK. Yes, I guess I would need the MR_ID to be set as an identity

Comment: I made the MR_ID an identity column but however, the row doesnt even insert now...